# Trying to upgrade to a new release version, having trouble with /etc/apt/sources.list

Tags: apt, updates

I am trying to upgrade to a new release version following the instructions of the accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release).

Someone mentioned in the comments section of the OP's question that you should change `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` to `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`
so that's what I did. The current state of my sources.list file is as shown below.

[image]
[image]

When I try to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, I get

```
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                            
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                                                            
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:5 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                         
Ign:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease                       
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bit-team/stable/ubuntu disco InRelease
Ign:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Err:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu disco Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What should I do?

Comment: First, mark your calendar so you don't let your release go EOL again. Second, use `old-releases` to bring your disco as far along as you can (`sudo apt full-upgrade`). Then run `do-release-upgrade` to migrate to 19.10 or `do-release-upgrade -d` to migrate to 20.04.

Comment: @user535733 `do-release-upgrade` worked. Thanks